# Best match between two sets of points

Tags: c#, algorithm, distance, minimum, points

I've got two lists of points, let's call them L<sub>1</sub>( P<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>), ... P<sub>n</sub>(x<sub>n</sub>, y<sub>n</sub>)) and L<sub>2</sub>(P'<sub>1</sub>(x'<sub>1</sub>, y'<sub>1</sub>), ... P'<sub>n</sub>(x'<sub>n</sub>, y'<sub>n</sub>)).

My task is to find the best match between their points for minimizing the sum of their distances.

Any clue on some algorithm? The two lists contain approx. 200-300 points.

Thanks and bests.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how do you define a `best match`? Does our task includes selecting a point from list L2 for each point in L1?

Comment: Suppose you have 3 points in each list: P1, P2, P3 and P'1, P'2, P'3. You can match them in following ways: P1-P'1, P2-P'2, P3-P'3 or P1-P'2, P2-P'1, P3-P'3 etc...Find the best match such that the sum of the couple distances is minimum. As SaiBot stated, the Hungarian algorithm is one option. I'm having a look at it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the use case of your problem involves matching ever point present in list L<sub>1</sub> with a point in list L<sub>2</sub>, then the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) would serve as a perfect fit.

The weights corresponding to your Hungarian matrix would be the distance between the point annotated for the row vs the column. The overall runtime for the optimized Hungarian algorithm is O(n<sup>3</sup>) which will comfortably fit for your given constraint of `n = 300`

A pretty nice tutorial covering the ideology and implementation of the Hungarian algorithm is https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/assignment-problem-and-hungarian-algorithm/

If not for the Hungarian algorithm, you can also morph the given problem into a `max-flow-min-cost` problem - the details of which I'll omit for now but can discuss if required.

Comment: That's it. Thanks, I'll try to build my own H.A. implementation. I'll check your answer as correct (SaiBot replied in the correct way as well)