# Optimal merge of 2 unequal dataframes with spatial coordinates in R?

Tags: r, merge, matching, coordinate-systems, array-merge

I need some help here. I'm trying to merge 2 dataframes (`WIDE.2018` and `WIDE.2015`) with different number of columns and rows. Sorry I can't share the data. Both have the a similar set of columns with spatial coordinates (`lon` and `lat`). I'm trying to merge both of them by the best unique pairs (something such as `optimal`) or by `nearest` with `replace=F` (I'm using an analogy to `MatchIt` terminology). I only could handle a `cbind` that finds the closest distance but allows repeating observations.

As mentioned by Geoffrey(thks!), I'm looking to find the optimal 1:1 matching that minimizes euclidean distance across all matches, ensuring that each point has only one match in the other data.frame (with some points being unmatched in the longer data.frame).

```
library (geosphere)

D = distm(WIDE.2018[, c("lon","lat")], WIDE.2015[, c("lon","lat")])

m1<-cbind(WIDE.2018, WIDE.2015[apply(D, 1, which.min),])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might need a bit better description here.  If you are trying to find the closest point in 2015 for each point in 2018, can more than one point in 2015 map to a single point is 2018 and vice versa?  Or are you trying to find the optimal 1:1 matching that minimizes euclidean distance across all matches, ensuring that each point has only one match in the other data.frame (with some points being unmatched in the longer data.frame)?

Comment: Hello, the second option is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer:

[Best match between two sets of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500239/best-match-between-two-sets-of-points)

I think you are looking for the Hungarian Algorithm.  Here is an implementation in R that claims to work with a rectangular matrix (e.g., unequal sample sizes).

https://rdrr.io/cran/RcppHungarian/man/HungarianSolver.html

I believe the weights in the required matrix would be the distances between points.